# How do i get back rigify buttons blender 2.91

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, rigify

I have a working rigify rig but all the control buttons for ik/fk are gone in properties panel. How do you get them back

Comment: If you can find the properties panel, and the buttons appear when you create a new rigify rig, it may not be salvageable.